# Configurate file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, configuration

Is it possible to write something like this to .cfg file (= ale in string)?

```
[styles] 
help_lines = c = 'silver', ls = "dashed"
```

for this in another file

```
plt.plot([1, 10],[2, 2], cfg['styles']['help_lines'])
```

**EDIT after advise:**

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 11,
          'font.family' : 'lmodern',
          'text.latex.unicode': True,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

How to write this to myconfig.py and how to include this to script.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one could use a python file for that

**myconfig.py**

```
class styles:
    helper_lines = dict(c  = "silver",
                        ls = "dashed")
```

**script.py**

```
import myconfig as cfg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], **cfg.styles.helper_lines)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you and could you please help me with edit in my question please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module?

Here's what you can do:

- **config.ini**

  ```
  [styles] 
  help_lines = silver
  c = silver
  ls = dashed
  ```
- **Usage:**

  ```
  cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
  cfg.read('/path/to/config.ini')

  print(cfg['styles']['help_lines'])
  # silver
  ```